# How to do operation on dataframe column in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

Job is to create a new column with diff between years count like 2002 data - 2001 data

Input:

```
+----+-------------------+
|col1|col2               |
+----+-------------------+
|2001 |10.              |
|2002 |15.              |
|2003 |19.              |
+----+-------------------+
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------------+
|col1|col2   |col3   |
+----+-------------------+
|2001 |10.  |     0     |
|2002 |15.  |     5     |
|2003 |19.  |     4     |
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: use lag window function

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lag, _}

val yearCol = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("col1")
result.withColumn("lag",(col("col2") - (lag(col("col2"), 1).over(yearCol)))).show
```

if required handle the null values for the first position.